# Encrypted files in Ubuntu Distro

Tags: 20.04, encryption

Previous question closed before I succeeded to find clarifying information. And thus I forced to re-post as a new question:

I'm looking for information regarding encrypted files that exist in Ubuntu Distribution media (20.04, 18.04, 16.04 maybe even earlier).

Our security procedures require a scan of any files that are transferred between network zones and unfortunately scan fails because of these files

Any idea, what are these files used for?

**Here is the file: /pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187_all.deb**

The file located in the **ubuntu-20/04-live-server-amd64.iso**

Comment: Please do not create the same topic twice.

Comment: This file is not encrypted. You can open it with e.g Archive Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Normally nothing is encrypted - it might be that you mean binary-files.

You can search for any package in the repository via this page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Regarding the package linux-firmware_1.187_all.deb you can find a list of the included files here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/linux-firmware/filelist

For further investigations I would recommend you to have a look at the source-code-package here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/all/linux-firmware

and if you wnat to get fully into the rabbit hole take a look here:
[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/tree/](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/tree/)

Hope this was a help.